# Call jquery tag in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>    
    function addMoreAns() {
        $(".add").append("<h1>Hi</h1>")
    }
</script>
```

It is my jquery tag in javascript function.
jquery tag don't work under javascript function

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? There is no such thing as a "jQuery tag".

Comment: Show all the relevant code. When/where is this function being called?

Comment: Provide more context please, such as when and where are you calling the function

Comment: Umm jQuery is javascript?

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also click `<>` icon in the header in edit mode to add a demo.

Comment: So how is `addMoreAns` called? What is the error? Your question is impossible to answer with the details provided.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't included jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have three things for your code to work:

1. You must make sure to have the JQuery library referenced prior to your use of any JQuery code.
2. In the HTML, you must have an element that is allowed to contain content with an `add` class.
3. You must **invoke your function** somehow. Just writing a function isn't the same thing as running it. You have to decide when the function should run and set up your code to invoke it at that point.

In the example below, the function is invoked every time the button is clicked.

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", addMoreAns);

function addMoreAns() {
  $(".add").append("<h1>Hi</h1>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click to Add">
<div class="add"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the jQuery library in the head of your page

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```